# contents of one array to another array

Tags: java

How can I take the contents of one array and put it in another array. I'm trying to call a function that takes a array and places it's contents into another array.

```
public String[] new_list;
public void setList(String list[]){

for (int i =0; i<list.length; i++)
list_command[i]= list[i];
}
```

Comment: Where are you having problems? Maybe you want to make a[ copy of the array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: Haha.. Sorry thought it was JS

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.copyOf` is what you are looking for. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

One of these should help:

1. `System.arraycopy()`
2. `Arrays.copyOf()`
3. `Arrays.copyOfRange()`

The choice depends on whether you are copying an array into a new array, part of an array into part of another, or part of an array into a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Given array

```
String[] list = {"1", "2", "3"};
```

Option 1:

```
String[] newList = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length); // create new and copy
```

Option 2:

```
String[] newList = new String[list.length]; // create new array
System.arraycopy(list, 0, newList, 0, list.length); // copy array content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.copyOf for copying contents of one Array into another. Refer the documentation in the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: Thank you solo much too!